# Is assignment and function value calculation an atomic operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, variable-assignment, atomic

I want to know if calculation of the function value and assignment of the result to a variable is an atomic operation in Java.

For example:

I have a thread-safe priority queue `q`. In `q` I save elements, and each element has a `rank` according to which it is placed in the queue. In addition I have a shared variable `topRank` that should always contain the rank of the topmost element in `q`. The following code is executed in parallel by number of threads:

```
element = q.remove(); // do something with element
topRank = q.peek();
```

could it happen that threadA would remove one elements from `q` and calculate value of `q.peek()` and just before assigning it to `topRank` would be interrupted by threadB, then threadB would remove one more element from `q` and update `topRank`. And then threadA would resume to assignment of incorrect value to the `topRank`.

A link to official literature would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that these operations are NOT atomic and you need to write the synchronization into your code.  This is a HUGE topic and there is a lot to learn about writing thread-safe programs.  Google for "java thread safety" and "java multithreading".

Comment: I Googled a lot before asking this question, but I haven't found somebody talking exactly about my case.

Comment: Your case is no different from any other thread-safety situation.  If you need an action to be atomic you have to make it synchronize on a monitor.  It may be as simple as making some methods `synchronized`, or it may be a lot more complex depending on your specific requirements, which we can't discern from your simple example.

Comment: Generally, I'm familiar with synchronization techniques. I just was doubting that because an assignment is such a basic operation it couldn't be interrupted. Thanks for clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safety only refers to the operation *within* the `remove()` or `peek()` calls. Unless you take steps to block threads from racing with each other, the race with `topRank` is entirely possible.

For more information, take a look at the [Java synchronization tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Answer (score 0):

1) I do not think that there are atomic operations, unless you protect them (synchronization and other technics).

2) That said, it does not apply to your example.

In your example you have.

a) Call `q.remove()`

b) `q.remove()` does its work (thread safe or not).

c) `q.remove()` returns a result

d) The result is assigned to `element` (this is the assignment!! all of before was just calculating the value to assign.)

---

So, it is not only if assignment (the last step in your operation) is atomic or not, you need to ensure that q.remove() is atomic too. And I assure you that it is not.

As it is not thread safe, if you want to avoid concurrent access you should synchronize the entire block.

---

EDIT answering the authors comment.

So what you are asking is if somehow `q.peek()` will return an elelent but another one will end in `topRank` due to other thread messing with it, isnt'it?

Unless `topRank` is shared by the different threads, it is not possible:

a) `q.peek()` runs its logic

b) the return value of `q.peek()` is copied (stored in the stack, back to expression that called `q.peek()`)

c) `q.peek()` exits. Only now other instances can access the synchronized section to change q.state, but the return value is already copied in the stack.

d) The copy in the stack is assigned to `topRank`

Comment: The `q.remove()` is do thread-safe as I use thread-safe version of priority queue (for instance I use PriorityBlockingQueue). The question was about assignment to `topRank` not to `element`.

Answer (score 0):

Calculation of a function value cannot possibly be atomic. The function could run for years before returning a value.